# Preprocessor macro to detect MSVC C Runtime libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Is there a preprocessor macro that is defined for each unique version of the MS C runtime libraries?

In particular, I would like to know in the code whether I am linking against the "multi-threaded" (MT) or "multi-threaded DLL" (MTD) versions.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what CRT you are going to link if you override the default.  Surely you'd be only interested in the _DEBUG macro.

Answer (score 2):

See [/MD, /MT, /LD (Use Run-Time Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2kzt1wy3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for VS2010 and other versions.

The macros are _MT and _DLL